# What are these fees attached to mutual fund FSEMX?

Tags: mutual-funds, etf, fees, tracking, expense-ratio

Could somebody please explain these fees attached to [FSEMX](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=FSEMX%20Profile)?

- Annual Report Expense Ratio (net)
- Prospectus Net Expense Ratio
- Prospectus Gross Expense Ratio

Finance.yahoo.com indicates that they are each .10%. Does that mean that if I add them all up, that the total expense ratio is .30%?

Also, if I was trying to decide between FSEMX and [VXF](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=VXF%20Profile), and VXF has a tracking error of .11%, which one is a better buy?

Comment: The annual expense ratio is required to be stated the same way by all investment companies. Have you tried going to the fund website and looking there? Also, do you have a tracking error for FSEMX to compare to the tracking error of VXF, or is the tracking error of FSEMX zero but it has larger expense ratio (say), and so you are asking is it better to pay more to FSEMX and get accurate tracking, or pay less to VXF and live with the tracking error? Is tracking error cumulative so that after two years VXF will be 0.22% off the mark? The annual expenses charged _will_ add up year after year.

Answer (score 1):

[**Annual-report expense ratios** reflect the actual fees charged during a particular fiscal year.](http://quicktake.morningstar.com/DataDefs/FundNutsAndBolts.html)

[**Prospectus Expense Ratio (net)** shows expenses the fund company anticipates will actually be borne by the fund's shareholders in the upcoming fiscal year less any expense waivers, offsets or reimbursements.](http://quicktake.morningstar.com/DataDefs/FundNutsAndBolts.html)

[**Prospectus Gross Expense Ratio** is the percentage of fund assets used to pay for operating expenses and management fees, including 12b-1 fees, administrative fees, and all other asset-based costs incurred by the fund, except brokerage costs. Fund expenses are reflected in the fund's NAV. Sales charges are not included in the expense ratio.](http://admainnew.morningstar.com/webhelp/glossary_definitions/mutual_fund/Prospectus_Gross_Expense_Ratio.htm)

All of these ratios are gathered from a fund's prospectus.

Comment: Yes, but do they add up so that if each is 0.1% as the OP says they are, then the investor pays 0.3% of assets per annum?

Comment: I think the total expense ratio that the OP would end up paying is 0.1%. The three figures are all expense ratios, and it is possible that they could differ because some expenses can be waived when calculating the figures. But, since they are all the same in this case, there are no such exclusions, so the expense ratio is 0.10%.

Answer (score 1):

FSEMX has an annual expense ratio of 0.1% which is very low. What that means
is that each month, the FSEMX will pay itself *one-twelfth* of 0.1% of 
the total value of all
the shares owned by the shareholders in the mutual fund.  If the fund has cash
on hand from its trading activities or dividends collected from companies 
whose stock is owned by FSEMX or interest on bonds owned by FSEMX, the 
money comes out of that, but if there is
no such pot (or the pot is not large enough), then the fund manager has the authority
to sell some shares of the stocks held by FSEMX so that the employees can be
paid, etc. If the total of cash generated by the trading and the dividend
collection in a given year is (say) 3% of the share value of all the outstanding mutual fund, 
then only 2.9% will be paid out as dividend and capital gain distribution 
income to the share holders, the remaining 0.1% already having been paid
to FSEMX management for operating expenses.

It is important to keep in mind that expenses are always paid even if
there are no profits, or even if there are losses that year so that
no dividends or capital gains distributions are made.  You don't see
the expenses explicitly on any statement that you receive.  If FSEMX
sells shares of stocks that it holds to pay the expenses, this reduces 
the share value (NAV) of the mutual fund shares that you hold.  So,
if your mutual fund account "lost" 20% in value that year because the
market was falling, and you got no dividend or capital gains distributions
either, remember that only 19.9% of that loss can be blamed on the
President or Congress or Wall Street or public-sector unions
or your neighbor's refusal to
ditch his old PC in favor of a new Mac, and the rest
(0.1%) has gone to FSEMX to pay for fees you agreed to when you
bought FSEMX shares.

If you invest directly in FSEMX through Fidelity's web site,
there is no sales charge, and you pay no expenses other than
the 0.1% annual expense ratio.  There *is* a fee for selling
FSEMX shares after owning them only for a short time since 
the fund wants to discourage short-term investors. Whatever
other fees finance.yahoo.com lists might be descriptive
of the uses that FSEMX puts its expense ratio income to
in its internal management,
but are not of any importance to the prudent investor in FSEMX
who will never encounter them or have to pay them.